# Can't compile std::map sorting, why?

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
map<string, int> errs;
struct Compare {
    bool operator() (map<string, int>::const_iterator l, 
        map<string, int>::const_iterator r) { 
        return ((*l).second < (*r).second); 
    }
} comp;
sort(errs.begin(), errs.end(), comp);
```

Can't compile. This is what I'm getting:

```
no matching function for call to ‘sort(..’
```

Why so? Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: whatever error you get it must be not possible to sort instance of std::map. It is sorted already and doesn't have to allow to sort itself like a std::vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maps are, by definition, sorted by their keys, so you can't resort a map by its values.

You can provide an alternate comparison function as the third template parameter to a map, if you want to sort the keys by a non-default order.

If you're trying to sort a map by its values, then perhaps you could try using [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) to make a [bidirectional map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/doc/examples.html#example4) instead?

Comment: Josh, many thanks for the answer and the links, they are very helpful!

Answer (score 10):

You can't sort a map. It has its own sort order, defined at construction time either as the default (use `<`) or a passed in comparator.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are doing `using namespace std;`. In that `sort` method requires the iterators to be random access iterators. But `map` iterators are bidirectional, so it will not compile.

Comment: +1, your answer is the only one that correctly address the OP problem (after fixing the `struct Compare` as suggested by Éric Malenfant here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2857350/15485 ). Unfortunately the OP omits the relevant part of the error message, something like `error: no match for 'operator-' in '__last - __first'` where the `operator-` is the one missing in the `map`'s bidirectional iterators. See for example http://ideone.com/i7atZ2

Answer (score 4):

This is probably because a std::map has a non-assignable iterator.

std::map has an invariant that is Strictly ascending order, it is always sorted by key.

Read more about it here:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/UniqueSortedAssociativeContainer.html

and note 1 here:
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Marcelo's answer: The predicate used by std::sort should take values, not iterators as input.

Comment: +1 For spotting the first problem in the OP snippet, Naveen spots the second problem in his answers http://stackoverflow.com/a/2857338/15485.

Answer (score 0):

As stated Marcelo you can't sort a map with std::sort you need to define the sort method in the constructor i believe is value_compare.

```
struct Compare
{
bool operator()(const char* a, const char* b) const
{
return strcmp(a,b) < 0;
};
std::map<char, char, Compare> compareMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Compare` template parameter takes map keys to compare (or references to keys), not the iterators. Also, the `std::map` takes that type at instantiation and is sorted automatically *by the key* (the most common implementation is the [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree)).

Take a look at [`boost::multi_index`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) for multi-key access.